# How to simulate button click

Tags: html, pagination

This is my pagination program :

```
     if(isset($_POST['view']))
 {
     $per_page = 20;
     if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
         $page = $_GET['page'];
     } else {
         $page = 1;

     }

     $start = $per_page * $page;
     $start = $start - $per_page;

     if(isset($_GET['seller']) ) {
         $seller = $_GET['seller'];
     } else {
         $seller = ($_POST['seller']);

     }

     echo $seller."_".$start;

     $query = "SELECT Kala.mark ,Kala.sharhe_kala, Kala_forooshande.date From Kala Join Kala_forooshande ON Kala.id_kala=Kala_forooshande.id_kala WHERE Kala_forooshande.id_forooshande=(SELECT id_forooshande From Forooshande where forooshande='". $seller ."')  LIMIT $start , $per_page";
     $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);

     $query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM Kala Join Kala_forooshande ON Kala.id_kala=Kala_forooshande.id_kala WHERE Kala_forooshande.id_forooshande=(SELECT id_forooshande From Forooshande where forooshande='". $seller ."')";
     $result2 = mysqli_query($db,$query2);

     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {


         echo " <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
         <table class='blueTable'><thead><tr><th>شماره</th><th>شرح کالا</th><th>مارک</th><th>تاریخ</th></tr></thead>";


         while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             $tarikh=gregorian_to_jalali((substr($row["date"],0,4)),(substr($row["date"],5,2)),(substr($row["date"],8,2)));
             $j=$start++;
             echo "<tr><td>" . $j . "</td><td>" . $row["sharhe_kala"] . "</td><td>" . $row["mark"] . "</td><td>" .$tarikh[0]."-".$tarikh[1]."-".$tarikh[2] . "</td></tr>";
         }
         echo "</table></form> ";


         $total = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
         $total_page = (ceil($total['total'] / $per_page));
         echo "<table class='pagination'>";
         $prev = $page - 1;
         if ($page <= 1) {
             echo "
            <td> << </td>
        ";
         } else {
             echo "
            <td><a href=\"?page=" . $prev . "\"> << </a></td>
        ";
         }

         for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_page; $i++) {

             if ($i == $page) {
                 echo "
                <td class='active'>$i</td>";
             } else {
                 echo "
                <td><a href=\"?page=" . $i . "&seller=".$seller."\">" . $i . "</a></td>";
             }
         }
         $next = $page + 1;
         if ($page >= $total_page) {
             echo "
             <td>>></td>
        ";
         } else {
             echo "
             <td><a href=\"?page=$next\"> >></a></td>
        ";
         }
         echo "</table>";
     }

  }
```

The problem is when the user click on page 2 , the `<a>` tag sends `<a href=\"?page=" . $i . "&seller=".$seller."\">"` to see the page number 2 , but it doesn't work because of  the if clause`if(isset($_POST['view'])` at the begining

So it just works for first page which the view button is clicked .

Is it possible to send button value in the link to simulate on button click event ?

Comment: The simplest approach seems to be just removing that `if` condition.  If you really want to use a form then you would want to replace your pagination links with buttons to submit your form(s).

Comment: if i remove `if` condition, the `table` would be shown in all condtions , but i want to be shown only if user click on view button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment on the question:

> i want to be shown only if user click on view button

Then you want more view buttons.  Replace your links with their own forms which post the values your server-side code expects.  So instead of this:

```
echo "
<td><a href=\"?page=" . $i . "&seller=".$seller."\">" . $i . "</a></td>";
```

You might have something like this:

```
echo "
<td>
    <form method=\"post\">
        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"page\" value=\"" . $i "\" />
        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"seller\" value=\"" . $seller "\" />
        <input type=\"submit\" name=\"view\" value=\"" . $i "\" />
    </form>
</td>";
```

You can use CSS to style your buttons to look like links if you prefer.  Tools like Boostrap make that very easy, just adding classes like `"btn btn-link"` to any clickable element for example.

But ultimately if you want your links to submit a form them make them forms.

Comment: @ZaGol: You’ll need to be more specific about what you tried and how it failed.  You are encouraged to update the question with new information.

Comment: Where is the ambiguous part to clarify it more ? I want to see the second and third page by clicking on its number but it shows nothing

Comment: The problem was here : `     if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
         $page = $_GET['page'];
     } else {
         $page = 1;

     }` I changed it and it is Ok now, thank you